# Odoo: A tree view where data comes from different models

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

In ODOO9, I want to display a tree view where fields contain computed values from different models within a period of time.
To be more explicit, user chooses a starting and an ending date, he must get the number of leaves of employees, the number of attended days... in the selected period.
Is there a way to do this?
Thank u in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [SO]. Please take time out for a [tour] and go though the [help]. You might also want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 possibilities:

1. Using a db view. there are enough examples in odoo like [Sales Report](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/sale/report/sale_report.py). Using a from and to date or something like that, has to be done in the search of odoo. That won't provide the best usability.
2. Implement a TransientModel/Wizard where you can enter from and to date, which will dynamically compute its lines (should also be transient). I think it will provide better usability but could be less performant.

Comment: Thank you CZoellner for your answer. I think the second possiblity would be a better solution in my case. I'll start working on it and I'll keep you up.

Answer (score 0):

Make a model with all the field that you want to display in tree view and then display them. It's not a big deal.

During your coding you may need to use related fields and relations for those I recommend you to read Odoo documentation.

That's all what you need to know for now

Good luck.